# Cluster objects by geometric coordinates (Y axis)

Tags: python, pandas, geometry, classification, cluster-analysis

I've got a pandas DataFrame with records describing rectangles with absolute coordinates of all the 4 points: TL (top-left), TR (top-right), BL (bottom-left) and BR (bottom-right). As it is, the rects seem to follow a row-like pattern, where there are conspicuous clusters forming "rows", like in this picture:

[image]

The data look like this:

```
    tl_x  tl_y  tr_x  tr_y  br_x  br_y  bl_x  bl_y  ht   wd
0   1567   136  1707   136  1707   153  1567   153  17  140
1   1360   154  1548   154  1548   175  1360   175  21  188
2   1567   154  1747   154  1747   174  1567   174  20  180
3   1311   175  1548   175  1548   196  1311   196  21  237
4   1565   174  1741   174  1741   199  1565   199  25  176
5   1566   196  1753   196  1753   220  1566   220  24  187
...
```

I need to cluster these objects along the `bl_y` or `br_y` column (bottom Y coordinate) to produce a 2D list of "rows" like:

[image]

As you see, objects in each "row" may have slightly varying Y coordinates (not exactly equivalent in each cluster). What I basically need is some function to add a separate e.g. `clustered_y` column to the DF and then sort by this column.

What's the simplest way to go?

Comment: Hint: you only need the BR (or BL) coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "tl_x": {0: 1567, 1: 1360, 2: 1567, 3: 1311, 4: 1565, 5: 1566},
        "tl_y": {0: 136, 1: 154, 2: 154, 3: 175, 4: 174, 5: 196},
        "tr_x": {0: 1707, 1: 1548, 2: 1747, 3: 1548, 4: 1741, 5: 1753},
        "tr_y": {0: 136, 1: 154, 2: 154, 3: 175, 4: 174, 5: 196},
        "br_x": {0: 1707, 1: 1548, 2: 1747, 3: 1548, 4: 1741, 5: 1753},
        "br_y": {0: 153, 1: 175, 2: 174, 3: 196, 4: 199, 5: 220},
        "bl_x": {0: 1567, 1: 1360, 2: 1567, 3: 1311, 4: 1565, 5: 1566},
        "bl_y": {0: 153, 1: 175, 2: 174, 3: 196, 4: 199, 5: 220},
        "ht": {0: 17, 1: 21, 2: 20, 3: 21, 4: 25, 5: 24},
        "wd": {0: 140, 1: 188, 2: 180, 3: 237, 4: 176, 5: 187},
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Calculate distance between "br_y" values
df = df.sort_values(by="br_y")
df["previous"] = df["br_y"].shift(1).fillna(method="bfill")
df["distance"] = df["br_y"] - df["previous"]

# Group values if distance > 5% of "br_y" values mean (arbitrarily chosen)
clusters = df.copy().loc[df["distance"] > 0.05 * df["br_y"].mean()]
clusters["clustered_br_y"] = [f"row{i}" for i in range(clusters.shape[0])]

# Add clusters back to dataframe and cleanup
df = (
    pd.merge(
        how="left",
        left=df,
        right=clusters["clustered_br_y"],
        left_index=True,
        right_index=True,
    )
    .fillna(method="ffill")
    .fillna(method="bfill")
    .drop(columns=["previous", "distance"])
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

```py
   tl_x  tl_y  tr_x  tr_y  br_x  br_y  bl_x  bl_y  ht   wd clustered_br_y
0  1567   136  1707   136  1707   153  1567   153  17  140           row0
1  1567   154  1747   154  1747   174  1567   174  20  180           row0
2  1360   154  1548   154  1548   175  1360   175  21  188           row0
3  1311   175  1548   175  1548   196  1311   196  21  237           row1
4  1565   174  1741   174  1741   199  1565   199  25  176           row1
5  1566   196  1753   196  1753   220  1566   220  24  187           row2
```